# UITableView reloadData() not working in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reloaddata

I have a tableView which I am trying to populate from Firebase, but I have a problem with reloadData(),it does not refresh the table.

This is my code:

```
 func showAnswers(pos: Int, name: String){
    let n = name
                
    answersReference.observe(DataEventType.value, with: {(snapshot) in
        if(!snapshot.exists()){
            
        }else{
            let answers = snapshot.children
            
            for answer in answers{
                let answersFromDB = AnswerFromDBObject()
                answersFromDB.setQuestion(question: (answer as! DataSnapshot).key)
                
                let ansData = (answer as! DataSnapshot).children
                
                for a in ansData{
                    answersFromDB.setAnswer(answer: (a as! DataSnapshot).key)
                }

                print("firebase answer: \(answersFromDB.getAnswer())")

                self.answerFromDBObject += [answersFromDB]
            }

            print("array count: \(self.answerFromDBObject.count)")

            self.userInfoAnwers.text = NSLocalizedString("users_questions", comment: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "(usernamehere)", with: n)
            self.answersTable.reloadData()

        }
    })
}
```

And my tableView delegate methods:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return answerFromDBObject.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "answersCell") as! SeeAnswersCell
    
    let answer = answerFromDBObject[indexPath.row]
    
    cell.question.text = answer.getQuestion()
    cell.answer.text = answer.getAnswer()
    
    return cell
}
```

These are print methods on console:

> firebase answer: Red 
> firebase answer: Fine
> firebase answer: London
> array count: 3

Comment: have you set the data source and delegate? does the delegate method called after reload?

Comment: Yes I have set them from storyboard, but delegate methods are not being called at all.

Comment: That doesn't seem right, try to re-set them, or do that in code

Comment: This doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try this after the final })

   DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.answersTable.reloadData()
   }

You are doing this to be able to reload it in the main thread

2. Check tableView delegate & data source connected
3. If you are using Xib cell, check if it's registered

Comment: Comment Updated, check it

Comment: Everything is connected, but not working.

Comment: did you do it after the }) ??